# Publish events from in recursive angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a `tree` component which is used recursively to render a tree that in component's HTML `tree` selector is used. Now `tree` components also expose an event as `nodeSelected`(`@Output`).

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of node">
        <div>
            <span (click)="treeNodeSelected(item)">
                {{item.name}}
            </span>
        </div>
        <tree *ngIf="item.child.length > 0" [node]="item.child" (nodeSelected)="treeNodeSelected($event)"></tree>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and here is the snippet from ts file

```
@Input("node") node;

@Output()
nodeSelected = new EventEmitter<any>(true);

..
..

treeNodeSelected(node) {
   console.log("node", node);
   this.nodeSelected.emit(node);
}
```

And the `actual-component` where I have used in `tree` component

```
<tree [node]="nodeData" (nodeSelected)="selectedNode($event)"></tree>
```

**ActualComponent.ts** file

```
selectedNode(node) {
    console.log("End Component",node);
}
```

And output on UI like

```
A
|-B
  |-C
```

Now If I click on **C** then on console

```
node {...}
node {...}
node {...}
component {...}
```

and If I click on **B** then on console

```
node {...}
node {...}
component {...}
```

and if on the top node ie on **A** then

```
node {...}
component {...}
```

I guess this is happening as `<tree>` inside the tree component markup should define the callback method from the **ActualComponent.ts** file but I have defined it from the **tree.ts** file. How can I achieve this? The ultimate goal is to emit event once.

Comment: I think `(nodeSelected)="treeNodeSelected($event)"` should be `(nodeSelected)="selectedNode($event)"`